# Recursive operations in SQL - lag on the same column

Tags: sql, recursion, vertica

I would like to do a recursive calculation in SQL, however, obviously I cannot lag over the column that is being created by the same query. Using the example `table`:

```
   Id   Column1    Column2
    1    5          10
    2    2          x
    3    3          y
```

I would like to replace x by 0.5 * 2 + 10 and y by 0.5 * 3 + x.

The query with `lag()` would look like this:

```
select 
Id
, Column1
, case when Id = 1 then 10
       when Id > 1 then 0.5 * Column1 + lag(Column2, 1) over (order by Id) 
       else null end as Column2 
from table
```

Is there a simple way to do this in SQL?

EDIT: This table will be much longer than the one in the example, so the solution should consider this.

Comment: Why isn't the first value `0.5 * 5 + 10` ?

Comment: I have the first value fixed from another query and it must stay constant. I updated the query.

Comment: Is ID a consecutive sequence, starting with 1, with no gaps in the numbers?

Comment: ID is based on time, I create it from the ordered sequence of datetimes. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

This below case statement

```
 when Id > 1 then 0.5 * Column1 + lag(Column2, 1) over (order by Id)
```

returns two values ID=2 and Id =3 hence returning incorrect values.

I know there will be better colution than this .

Check this out:

```
create table recur
(
  Id int,
  Column1 int,
  Column2 varchar(100)
 );

 insert into recur values ( 1,5,10);
 insert into recur values ( 2,2,'x');
 insert into recur values (3,3,'y');

    select * from 
    (select 
    a.Id,a.Column1,
    case   when a.Id = 1 then 10
           when a.Id =2 then (0.5 * a.Column1 + lag(a.Column2 , 1) over (order by a.Id) )
           else null end as Column2
    from recur a 
    union 
    select id,column1,
    case when Id =3 then (0.5 * Column1 + lag(Column2 , 1) over (order by Id) )end as Column2
    from
    (
    select 
    a.Id,a.Column1,
    case   when a.Id = 1 then 10
           when a.Id =2 then (0.5 * a.Column1 + lag(a.Column2 , 1) over (order by a.Id) )
           else null end as Column2
    from recur a)b
     )c
     where column2 is not null
```

Regards,
Saravanan

Comment: Thanks Saravanan, but this table by design will have thousands of rows, so I do not think this will be a proper solution :( I should have mentioned this at the beginning. Sorry